# Bash if statement working for one case and not for other

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I'm using bash to retrieve kernels from a cuda program using the following code:

```
kername="kernelnames"
loop="loop"
filecp="filecp"
funct="funct"
truncate -s 0 $kername
truncate -s 0 $loop
truncate -s 0 $funct
counter=1

funct_display(){
    count=0
    flag=1
    while read line ; do
        echo "$line"
        if [[ "$line" == "{" ]] ; then echo "$line"; count=$(( count+1 )) ; echo "$counter $count incre" ;fi
        if [[ "$line" == "}" ]] ; then count=$(( count-1 )) ; echo "$counter $count decre" ;fi      
        if [[ $count > 0 ]] ; then echo "$line" >> $funct ;fi
        if [[ $count == 0 ]] ; then flag=0 ; fi 
        if [[ $flag == 0 ]] ; then break ; fi   
        #if [[ $count == 0 ]] ; then counter=$(( counter+1 )); fi
        counter=$(( counter+1 ))        
    done < $filecp
    echo "}" >> $funct
    echo "" >>$funct
}
file_copy(){
    truncate -s 0 $filecp
    while read line; do
        echo "$line" >> $filecp
    done < $filename
}

read -p "Enter the name of the file to be scanned: " filename
var=$( grep "__global__" < $filename | wc -l )
echo "kernels" >> $kername
for((i=1;i<=$var;i++))
do
    temp1=$( grep -m$i "__global__" < $filename | tail -n1 )
    a=$( grep -n -m$i "__global__" < $filename | cut -d : -f 1 | tail -n1 )
    j=$(( i+1 ))
    temp2=$( grep -m$j "__global__" < $filename | tail -n1 )
    b=$( grep -n -m$j "__global__" < $filename | cut -d : -f 1 | tail -n1 )
    echo "$i $temp1 $a $b" >> $kername
    temp5=$( sed -n " $a , $b p" $filename )
    echo "$temp5" >> $loop
    #echo "$a"
    while read line ; do
        if [[ "$line" == "$temp1" ]] ; then 
            echo "$line " >> $funct
            echo "$line"
            file_copy
            for((k=$a;k>0;k--))
            do
                echo "$k"
                sed -i "${k}d" $filecp 
            done
            funct_display 
        fi
    done < $filename
    #echo "$temp1"
done
```

The above shell script is working for a program with following kernels:

```
__global__ void addKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}

__global__ void subKernel(int *c, const int *a, const int *b)
{
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    c[i] = a[i] - b[i];
}
```

But it won't work for a program with the following kernel:

```
__global__ void Vec_Mat_mul(float *gV, float*gM, float *gR, int Vecsize, int Matcols)

{   int i, j;
    float sum=0.0;
    i=(blockIdx.x*blockDim.x)+threadIdx.x; //For each block access
    if(i<Matcols)
{
        for(j=0;j<Vecsize;j++)
            sum=sum+(gV[j]*gM[j+(i*Vecsize)]);

        __syncthreads(); //Synchronization Barrier
        gR[i]=sum;
}
}
```

I figured that it is not entering the if statement : if [[ "$line" == "{" ]] for some reason but I can't understand why. Thank you in advance!

Comment: yes, you're right, `if [[ "$l{ine}" == "{" ]]` expects only the `{` char on a line. Try `if [[ "${line}" ~= "{" ]] ` . But that will match a `{` anywhere on the line. This would be much easier and efficient converting it to `awk`, but it seems you've already put a lot of time into this, so do what is best for your situation. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of things going wrong here.

1. as @shellter points out, `[[ "$line" == "{" ]]` tests if the entire line is equal to `{`, so fails on line 3 of file 2: `{   int i, j;`
2. before even reaching that point, blank line 2 of file 2 causes these to be true:

   ```
   if [[ $count == 0 ]] ; then flag=0 ; fi
   if [[ $flag == 0 ]] ; then break ; fi
   ```

breaking out of the `funct_display`'s `while` loop before reaching line 3.

perhaps you could rename/reframe your question to: how can i use command-line tools to extract CUDA kernel C code, and give an example of the output you're trying to get from your two input examples.

if you're looking for a quick fix that can at least handle these two examples, you could do a little preprocessing to put each curly brace alone on it's own line, and remove any blank lines or lines of nothing but whitespace:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\([{}]\)\(.*\)/\1\n\2\n\3/' file.c |
  grep -v '^\s*$' > file.preprocessed.c
```

Comment: Well, it turns out it was semantically correct but the file we were trying to process was somehow "corrupted". We copy pasted the contents in a new file and it worked flawlessly. Thanks for all the help though. :)

Comment: i'd be careful. i ran your sample code on your sample files and it didn't work on the second file. it seems like it may work for files where all the curly braces are alone on their own lines with no leading nor trailing spaces. though, admittedly, i don't know what your desired output is, so i can't say for sure that it's not working as intended, only that it behaves very differently for curly braces not alone on their own lines.